# Multiple form submission in cake php 3.0

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, form-submit

I am using cake php  3.0 to develop an application. When user try to edit his details the success flash message is appear multiple times as the form is submitted multiple times. I am using cake php form builder. Here is my code

```
<?= $this->Form->create('Project'); ?>  
    <?= $this->Html->link('  キャンセル 編集', array('action' => 'view', $project['id']), array('class' => 'btn btn-default pull-right', 'style' => 'margin: 5px 14px 0 0', 'rule' => 'button')); ?>
   <?= $this->Form->button(__('   保存 '), array('class' => 'btn btn-default pull-right', 'style' => 'margin: 5px 14px 0 0 ',  'id' => 'edit', 'onsubmit'=> 'disable()')); ?>
  <h3 style="font-weight:bold; padding-left:10px; margin: 10px 0 20px;"> 案件基本情報 </h3>

   <section id="unseen">
   <div class="col-sm-12" role="complementary">
    <div class="panel panel-default" >
    <div class="panel-body table-responsive" style ="padding:0px !important">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed f11 table-nowrap " style ="margin:0px; ">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td width="23%" class="numeric cell-bg">案件ID</td>
            <td class="numeric">
              <?php if ($project['survey_status'] == $this->Comm->DbConst('PROJECT_SURVEY_STATUS_NEW')) { ?>
                <?= $this->Form->input('survey_id', array('type' => 'text', 'class' => 'form-control', 'required' => true, 'label' => false, 'value' => __($project['survey_id']))) ?> <div style="color:red;"><?php
                if (!empty($errors['survey_id'])) {
                  echo reset($errors['survey_id']);
                }
                ?></div></td>
            <?php } else { ?>
                  <?= $this->Form->input('survey_id', array('type' => 'text', 'class' => 'form-control', 'required' => false, 'label' => false, 'disabled' => true, 'value' => __($project['survey_id']))) ?> </td>
                <?php } ?>
            <td width="30%" colspan="2"  class="numeric cell-bg">運用者名</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="numeric cell-bg">案件名</td>
            <td class="numeric"><?= $this->Form->input('title', array('type' => 'text', 'class' => 'form-control', 'required' => true, 'label' => false, 'value' => __($project['title']))) ?> <div style="color:red;"><?php
                if (!empty($errors['title'])) {
                  echo reset($errors['title']);
                }
                ?></div></td>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="3" class="numeric"> 
              <div class="selectRow">             
                <select class="operator form-control" style="max-width:100%; " name="operator[]" data-placeholder="運用者選択" multiple required >
                  <?php foreach ($operators as $operator) { ?>
                    <option value=<?php
                    echo $operator['id'] . ":" . $operator['username'];
                    ?> selected><?php echo h($operator['username']); ?></option>
                          <?php } ?>
                </select>
                <div style="color:red;"><?php
                  if (!empty($errors['operator'])) {
                    echo reset($errors['operator']);
                  }
                  ?></div>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="numeric cell-bg"><strong>顧客情報</strong></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="numeric cell-bg">会社名</td>
            <td class="numeric"><?= $this->Form->input('company_name', array('type' => 'text', 'class' => 'form-control', 'required' => true, 'label' => false, 'value' => __($project['company_name']))) ?> <div style="color:red;"> <?php
                if (!empty($errors['company_name'])) {
                  echo reset($errors['company_name']);
                }
                ?></div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="numeric cell-bg">部署名</td>
            <td class="numeric"><?= $this->Form->input('department_name', array('type' => 'text', 'class' => 'form-control', 'required' => true, 'label' => false, 'value' => __($project['department_name']))) ?> <div style="color:red;"><?php
                if (!empty($errors['department_name'])) {
                  echo reset($errors['department_name']);
                }
                ?></div></td>
            <td colspan="2" class="numeric cell-bg">参照者 </td>
          </tr>      
          <tr>
            <td class="numeric cell-bg">管理者氏名</td>
            <td class="numeric"><?= $this->Form->input('name', array('type' => 'text', 'class' => 'form-control', 'required' => true, 'label' => false, 'value' => __($project['name']))) ?><div style="color:red;"> <?php
                if (!empty($errors['name'])) {
                  echo reset($errors['name']);
                }
                ?></div></td>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="3" class="numeric">
              <div class="selectRow">             
                <select class="viewer form-control" style="max-width:100%;" name="viewer[]" data-placeholder="参照者選択" multiple required >
                  <?php foreach ($viewers as $viewer) { ?>
                    <option value=<?php echo $viewer['id'] . ":" . $viewer['username']; ?> selected><?php echo h($viewer['username']); ?></option>
                  <?php } ?>
                </select>             
                <div style="color:red;"><?php
                  if (!empty($errors['viewer'])) {
                    echo reset($errors['viewer']);
                  }
                  ?></div>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="numeric cell-bg">管理者アカウント</td>
            <td class="numeric"><?= $this->Form->input('air_id', array('type' => 'text', 'class' => 'form-control', 'required' => true, 'label' => false, 'value' => __($project['air_id']))) ?> <div style="color:red;"><?php
                if (!empty($errors['air_id'])) {
                  echo reset($errors['air_id']);
                }
                ?></div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="numeric cell-bg">管理者メールアドレス</td>
            <td class="numeric"><?= $this->Form->input('email', array('type' => 'email', 'class' => 'form-control', 'required' => true, 'label' => false, 'value' => __($project['email']))) ?><div style="color:red;"> <?php
                if (!empty($errors['email'])) {
                  echo reset($errors['email']);
                }
                ?></div></td>
          </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Form->end() ?>

How to prevent multiple submission. Either using cake php's functionality or using any other methods. I have tried loading csrf component but that doesn't worked for me.

Comment: Please post the full form or the full view file.

Answer (score 0):

What i do to prevent multiple form submission, is after the submission and action has done it's work, i redirect to another url or the same.

```
<?php

public function add(){
    //Grab data and validate it
    if($this->save($data)){
        $this->Flash->set(...);
        return $this->redirect(array('action', 'index')); // redirect to prevent resubmission
    }
    //Do other processing ...

}
```

Comment: I had already redirecting it to other page then also the resubmission is happening

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, duplicate form submissions is usually always double-clicks...etc.  Simply making your submit `<button>` call a JavaScript function that disables the button then submits the form should keep this from happening.

You could think about adding a unique ID to the form in a hidden field, to detect any duplicate submissions that still make it through, but that first option should do the trick.